# How do I install Tensorflow 2.4.0?

Tags: tensorflow, python-3.9, junit-jupiter

Noob question. Thanks for bearing with me.

I have Tensorflow 2.4.1 installed on my computer, but I need 2.4.0 version for compatibility with a specific project.

I tried the following without success:

```
conda install tensorflow==2.4.0
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow==2.4.0
```

It does this for awhile until jupyter notebook tells me that it couldn't find what I need

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment:
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
                                                                               failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

  - tensorflow==2.4.0 -> python[version='3.6.*|3.7.*|3.8.*']
  - tensorflow==2.4.0 -> python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0']

Your python: python=3.9

If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for.
When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow
not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not
change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify
that.
```

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an environment based on tensorflow 2.4.0:

```
conda create --name tf_2.4.0 tensorflow=2.4.0
```

and then activate it:

```
conda activate tf_2.4.0
```

That will install all you need using tensorflow 2.4.0 as a dependency. For example, you should get python-3.8.12 !

Comment: I ended up reinstalling Anaconda. But I'm sure this would have worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

According to the tensorflow official site - [https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#:~:text=System%20requirements,-Python%203.7%E2%80%933.10&text=Python%203.9%20support%20requires%20TensorFlow,requires%20TensorFlow%202.2%20or%20later](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#:%7E:text=System%20requirements,-Python%203.7%E2%80%933.10&text=Python%203.9%20support%20requires%20TensorFlow,requires%20TensorFlow%202.2%20or%20later).

[image]

Tf 2.4 is not supported by python 3.9, so you need to install a different version of python preferable 3.8 inside conda, and only then you can install TF 2.4

Comment: Thanks. What I don't understand how Tensorflow 2.12.0 comes installed in Colab specially now they've upgraded to Python 3.10?